# How to change hashbang url to history API

Tags: ember.js, html5-history

I'm using ember1.0-rc3, i want to change hashbang urls into normal url format (ie, www.site.com/admin#/page1 to www.site.com/admin/page1).In order to make this change,i use location: "history" in app router.

But when i reload a page or bookmark a page doesn't works, it redirects to home page only.I want the options reload and bookmark in my app, without changing redirect urls in .htaccess file.Is there any way for it?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use HTML5 history with a single page app like ember, your server must be have the behavior of rendering your main index.html file for any URL. The Ember router has the logic to look at the URL when it loads and go to the correct route.

Comment: thanks...But to make my server serves index.html for any URL, i have to change it in .htaccess file.Without changing in server side to implement this,is there any option to change it in client side?

Comment: No, it's not possible to make the history approach work without server support.